# Making a bridge on a cyclic molecule

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis, alcohols

So, my question is how would I make a bridge as seen on the following molecule (right side)?

[image: Left side is Molecule A, right side is Molecule B]

As for the molecule on the left, I am supposed to make it using that molecule as a base. The only requirement is that every other molecule I use that uses carbon, can only have a maximum of 2 carbons.

To reiterate- I need to use the molecule in the left using any inorganic compound, and organic molecules with up to 2 carbons, and turn it into the molecule in the right.

My biggest problem here, is how to make it so that the molecule only reacts in that area. I was thinking of using a mixture of condensation and $\ce{HBr}$ in order to break the $\ce{-OH}$, and temporarily remove a hydrogen.

However, again, I don't know how to make it so it would only react in that specific area.

Comment: This is non-trivial.

Comment: This is most definitely not a homework question, so the close votes do not make sense.